# How do I get user input and save it using asyncstorage and provide this information to other pages?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

This is part of an appointment booking app for a jewelry store. The users cannot buy from the store using the app, but can only make an appointment for custom designed jewelry.

After the user enters their info, they'll press {buttons.send} that'll send a confirmation code to either their phone number or email. A confirmation screen will appear where the code is entered to complete the registration process. See https://github.com/yhenni1989/authentication for screenshots - I'm unable to upload photos at the moment. I'm using his code as a foundation. 
I have setup the hooks, but i don't know how to specify the logic and pass down the information.
I would also appreciate an example of how to use firebase Auth, with hooks, using the users username and password for the sign in screen.

```
const SignUp = ({ navigation: { navigate } }) => {

  const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [phone, setPhone] = useState('');


  return (
    <Container>
      <Centered>
        <TextInput placeholder={placeholders.username} />
        <TextInput placeholder={placeholders.password} password />
        <TextInput
          placeholder={placeholders.email}
          keyboardType="email-address"
        />
        <TextInput placeholder={placeholders.phone} keyboardType="phone-pad" />
        <Text onPress={() => navigate(routes.login)}>{messages.already}</Text>
      </Centered>
      <Centered>
        <Button onPress={() => navigate(routes.confirm)}>
          <Text color={colors.bright}>{buttons.send}</Text>
        </Button>
      </Centered>
    </Container>
  )
}

export default SignUp;
```

Comment: Take a step back from "logic", "hooks", "passing information", "async storage", etc. These are all technical details that may or may not be related to your question. Instead, you should describe in words what your app is supposed to do. You can also add mock screens to illustrate, by drawing them in MS Paint or something similar. You clearly have a sign up page here where the user can enter a username, password and some other info. After the user clicks on the button, what should happen next?

Comment: I have added more info. I hope it's clear.